# How to send a filename to start a Dash App

Tags: plotly-dash

I can start a Dash app by using app.run(debug=True)

Now, I need to send a filename to start the Dash App. The Dash App will load the file from the filename, and then do some calculations. How to do that/load filenames to start the app?

Did not find examples online